# `gdal_calc.py` only outputs as Int16 even though set to Float32

Tags: gdal, gdal-calc

The following code only outputs integer even though set to float32.

```
'gdal_calc.py -A input_raster.tif --A_band 1 --outfile output_raster.tif --calc "0.005 * A.astype(float)" --NoDataValue -32767 --type Float32'
```

The `input_raster.tif` is `Float32`.

I have followed all the solutions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108718/does-gdal-calc-py-not-calculate-arithmetic-with-in-the-same-file) but it is not working.

Comment: Do you remove the existing output_raster.tif before running? Have you tried --NoDataValue -32767.0, I know it shouldn't make a difference as you're implicitly specifying --type Float32. What version of GDAL are you using (GDALINFO --VERSION)?

Comment: @Luke, I couldn't generate stat as I deleted all the files.

Comment: @MichaelStimson the cause of the problem could be existing input file. So what I was doing was calculate using input_raster. output_raster already exists but I though it will be overwritten most likely it is not. Could you answer it please. Your idea helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of it you were retaining the existing output file expecting it to be overwritten with a new file created using the `-type Float32` parameter but the tool has not recreated the file, which is Int16, as Float32 but simply reused the existing raster completely ignoring all the creation options.

This may be intentional, like in GDAL_Rasterize, to force a particular datatype or may be a quirk of your particular GDAL version or even a partially locked file (unable to delete but write access can be granted).

Comment: +1 Confirmed - `gdal_calc.py` will write into an existing file if `-overwrite` is not set. However, if the `-overwrite` option is set, the existing file is deleted and a new one created - [source](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py#L195).

Comment: @Luke I didn't know about it. Is this option there in `gdalwrap`and `gdal_translate` too?

Comment: @wondim - `gdal_translate` no, it will overwrite by default, `gdalwarp` has a `-overwrite` option as it supports writing/appending/mosaicing into an existing file and will behave the same as `gdal_calc.py`.